# Call multiple $http request with nested data in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I a new in AngularJS. In my project, I will call multi $http request on time. But, data in success in before $http request is a parameter in next $http request.

I have try this:

```
$http.post(URL1, params1).success(function(data){
     $http.post(URL2, data.result).success(function(){
          ......
     })
}).error(function(err){})
```

But it make complicate and hard to handle it. How to resovle it? Thanks.

Comment: This is not parallel. These are nested sequential calls.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit my question title :)

Comment: using `.success` is depreciated you should stick to using `.then`

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to control asynchronous operations [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) or you could use [vasync](https://github.com/davepacheco/node-vasync) which is like async but with better logging.

```
var postSomething1 = function(cb) {
    $http.post(URL1, params1).success(function(data){
        cb(null, data);
    })
    .error(cb);
};
var putSomething = function(cb) {
    $http.put(URL1, params1).success(function(data){
        cb(null, data);
    })
    .error(cb);
};

var tasks = [
    postSomething,
    putSomething
];
var done = function(err, result){
    console.log("Complete with err", err, " result", result);
};

async.parallel(tasks, done);
```

as you have more methods, you realize you can refactor like this:

```
var call = function(method, url, params) {
    return function(cb) {
        var method = method.toLowerCase();
        $http[method](url, params).success(function(data){
            cb(null, data);
        })
        .error(cb);
    };
};
var tasks = [
    call('POST', 'http://example.com/create/event', { event_name: 'Cool' }),
    call('PUT', 'http://example.com/update', { name: 'Jon' }),
    call('PUT', 'http://example.com/event/enable', { enable: true }),
    call('GET', 'http://example.com/list/34')
    ...
];
var done = function(err, result){
    console.log("Complete with err", err, " result", result);
};

async.parallel(tasks, done);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example you can do it like this way

```
var FlightDashboard = function( $scope, user, travelService, weatherService )
    {
        // Level 1
#
        travelService
            .getDeparture( user.email )                 // Request #1
            .then( function( departure )                // Response Handler #1
            {
                $scope.departure = departure;
#
                // Level 2
#
                travelService
                    .getFlight( departure.flightID )        // Request #2
                    .then( function( flight  )              // Response Handler #2
                    {
                        $scope.flight = flight;
#
                        // Level 3
#
                        weatherService
                            .getForecast( departure.date )      // Request #3
                            .then( function( weather )          // Response Handler #3
                            {
                                $scope.weather = weather;
                            });
                    });
            });
    };
```